# Play framework AngularJs CORS post json

Tags: json, scala, post, playframework-2.0, cors

I have a frontend in AngularJs and a playframework 2 Scala backend. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530273/composing-with-plays-essentialaction) to add CORs to the backend - I have two endpoints a GET and POST

```
GET         /api/question/:id              controllers.Questions.getQuestion(id: String)
POST        /api/question/:id              controllers.Questions.postQuestion(id: String)
```

This solution provided in the other response works for the GET but not for the POST

```
def getQuestion(key:String) = CorsAction{
    ....

  }




def postQuestion(key:String) = CorsAction(parse.json){
               req =>
      ........
  }
```

What I understood is that the `CORsAction` (which extends `ActionBuilder`) can also accept methods which a bodyparser and thus should essentially work for POST requests as well.

This is what I see in the browser console when i hit POST from my front end.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:9000/api/question/abc123 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access. angular.js:7997
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/api/question/abc123. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure the exact problem but adding the following to the routes
fixed the problem

```
OPTIONS        /api/question/:id             controllers.Application.preflight(id)
```

Where the preflight endpont just returns Ok with the CORs headers. But I would have thought that the CorsAction was supposed to take care of this. Anyways, moving on.

Comment: How are you returning the CORS headers? Using `Ok().withHeaders(...)`?

Comment: for each of your `Ok(...)`, did you add `withHeaders(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*")`? I was able to resolve my CORS issue by appending that `withHeaders` to each of my HTTP Response Headers - not only the pre-flight response's header.

Comment: I just had to add that to my OPTIONS request. Not for the GET / POST if thats what you mean.

Comment: Hmm, only **after** adding the `withHeaders(...)` to my `GET / POST` requests too did CORS work for me.